# JMeter save load time into a variable

Tags: jmeter, load-time

I cannot seem to save the load/response/sample time into a variable using RegEx.
[Sampler Results page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c7hd.png)

Is there a way to access the results from the Sampler Results page?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot extract Response time using regular expressions because regular expression extractor is limited to the following options and response time is calculated by JMeter

[image]

However you can use [JMeter's SampleResult api](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) to get load time.
The api has methods for [endtime](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getEndTime--) and [starttime](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getStartTime--) of a sample, using this methods  you can calculate load time and then store it in JMeter variable.

```
Loadtime= endtime-starttime
```

Add a Beanshell post processor to your sampler and add the following code to the post processor

```
long starttime=prev.getStartTime();

long endtime=prev.getEndTime();

int loadtime=endtime-starttime;

vars.put("Load time",Integer.toString(loadtime));
```

You can use ${Load time} to get load time of that particular sample
[image]

More info:

[Regular expression extractors](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

[Beanshell](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/4878/)